# My .htaccess RewriteRule is "not working"

Tags: php, url-rewriting, rule

```
RewriteRule ^word-(.*)/(.*)/([a-z][a-z])/([0-9]+)?/$ /keywordbycountry.php?word=yes&keyword=$2&cc=$3&page=$4 [L]
```

the $2 = is the keyword (anything)
the $3 is the country code (only 2 lowercase letters)
the $3 is the page (only numbers)

but for some reason it is not working

Comment: Please post the url you're requesting, what do you expect and what do you get

Comment: much easier to accomplish with php instead of doing everything with a apache rewrite

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working". Are things doing into the wrong variables? Do you get a 500 error? Something else? Try just doing a "var_dump($_GET);" in the keywordbycountry.php file to see what's being passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^word-(.*)/([a-z]+)/([a-z][a-z])/([0-9]+)?/$ /keywordbycountry.php?word=yes&keyword=$2&cc=$3&page=$4 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

".*" might be the problem, it will match anything and therefore also '/' up until the strings end is reached.

use [^/]+ instead:

```
RewriteRule ^word-([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([a-z][a-z])/([0-9]+)?/$ /keywordbycountry.php?word=yes&keyword=$2&cc=$3&page=$4 [L]
```